# How can I package a unsigned app in iOS when I'm using the Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, build, package, unsigned

Background : I'm using some Oracle product (OMSS), and need to get an unsigned app before publish as Enterprise app.

I tried use the

```
xcodebuild clean build -project BitzerSecureContainer.xcodeproj -target Bitzer CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -configuration Release
```

But it seems I have dependency issue when using cocoapods. Using `BitzerSecureContainer.xcworkspace` instead of  `BitzerSecureContainer.xcodeproj` in command line doesn't help either .

So how can I get a unsigned app with Cocoapods? THX~

Comment: If you mean you want to archive a release build, you can't do it without code signing!

Comment: @Ariel Not  release build . I want to import an unsigned app , do something, then signing the code separately .

Comment: Sometimes Xcode complains it needs to  sign for some project for packaging. And, I would like to know how to do it without codesign as well.